# How to use expect to execute a jar and continuously hit enter?

Tags: jar, ansible, redhat, expect, autoexpect

To start from the beginning, I'm using ansible to open a Jar file in a linux environment.

Basically I do: java -jar someJarFile.jar, and it opens in command line.
Now, it prompts me with several questions which can be passed by hitting Return multiple times.
Finally the jar will produce a WAR file...

Here's where I need your help.
I want to use ansible to call an expect script so that it can automatically execute the jar and continuously hit enter until the jar is successfully completed/installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
yes "" | java -jar someJarFile.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of times you need to press `<Enter>` you can use `echo -e '\n'`. For example, if you know you'll need three `<Enter>`s:

```
echo -e '\n\n\n' | java -jar someJarFile.jar
```

This is also helpful for times when you need to input specific and distinct values which `yes` doesn't allow. For example, answering a prompt like:

```
Enter value [default]: <enter>
Enter number: 30<enter>
Ok?: y<enter>
Do the dangerous: n<enter>
```

Could be simulated by

```
echo -e '\n30\ny\nn\n' | java -jar someJarFile.jar
```